# procedimiento almacenado en oracle

Tags: oracle

tengo un pequeño problema, estoy practicando procedimientos almacenados en oracle he intentado realizar un procedimientos almacenados (CRUD), cada procedimiento debe mostrar mensaje, ejemplo: si es insertar debe decir “Registro insertado” y así el mensaje de acuerdo al procedimiento

alguien me puede dar una idea de como hacerlo por favor

hice uno pero en sql server he intentado hacerlo igual oracle pero no me funciona

```
create PROCEDURE crudInsertar
(
@Nombre_Establecimiento varchar(300),
@Actividad varchar(300),
@Nit varchar(20),
@Direccion varchar(300),
@Telefono varchar(15)
)
AS

insert into COMERCIO_BOGOTA (Nombre_Establecimiento, Actividad, Nit, Direccion, Telefono ) values
(@Nombre_Establecimiento, @Actividad, @Nit, @Direccion, @Telefono)
PRINT 'SE INSERTO EXITOSAMENTE'


EXEC crudInsertar   'sdg', 'nbsx de software', '234', 'cra 10 no 55', '09875'
```

Comment: La sintaxis es muy diferente y no va a funcionar llevándolo de un motor a otro. Te recomiendo buscar en la documentación, reescribir el procedimiento y probar tu código. Si no funciona, puedes traerlo. De paso, procura especificar siempre en qué versión de BD estás trabajando.

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta y pon el código del procedimiento Oracle que usaste. Confirma además que se compila y no sale "compilado con errores". Lo otro: desde dónde lo estás ejecutando? SQL developer, SQL*plus, otro editor? Decir "no me funciona" es muy amplio y es difícil saber cuál es el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo un paquete PL/SQL el cual contiene un procedimiento almacenado de insertar, te puedes basar en el y hacer el resto

```
----ENCABEZADO DEL PAQUETE INSERTAR-----
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Pack_Insertar
    IS
    PROCEDURE P_Insertar (P_RINCIPIO_ACTIVO PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO%type, U_NIDAD_DE_DISPENSACION PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.UNIDAD_DE_DISPENSACION%type, C_ONCENTRACION PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.CONCENTRACION%type,
    U_NIDAD_BASE PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.UNIDAD_BASE%TYPE, N_OMBRE_COMERCIAL PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.NOMBRE_COMERCIAL%TYPE, F_ABRICANTE PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.FABRICANTE%TYPE,
    P_RECIO_POR_TABLETA PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.PRECIO_POR_TABLETA%TYPE, F_ACTORESPRECIO PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.FACTORESPRECIO%TYPE, N_UMEROFACTOR PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.NUMEROFACTOR%TYPE);
END Pack_Insertar;


---CUERPO DEL PAQUETE INSERTAR
create or replace PACKAGE BODY Pack_Insertar
    IS
    PROCEDURE P_Insertar (P_RINCIPIO_ACTIVO PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.PRINCIPIO_ACTIVO%type, U_NIDAD_DE_DISPENSACION PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.UNIDAD_DE_DISPENSACION%type, C_ONCENTRACION PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.CONCENTRACION%type,
    U_NIDAD_BASE PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.UNIDAD_BASE%TYPE, N_OMBRE_COMERCIAL PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.NOMBRE_COMERCIAL%TYPE, F_ABRICANTE PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.FABRICANTE%TYPE,
    P_RECIO_POR_TABLETA PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.PRECIO_POR_TABLETA%TYPE, F_ACTORESPRECIO PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.FACTORESPRECIO%TYPE, N_UMEROFACTOR PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS.NUMEROFACTOR%TYPE)
    is
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO PRECIOS_MEDICAMENTOS VALUES(P_RINCIPIO_ACTIVO, U_NIDAD_DE_DISPENSACION, C_ONCENTRACION, U_NIDAD_BASE, N_OMBRE_COMERCIAL,F_ABRICANTE, P_RECIO_POR_TABLETA,F_ACTORESPRECIO,N_UMEROFACTOR);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Se agrego registros');
    END P_Insertar;
END Pack_Insertar;
```

luego pruebas el paquete añadiendo un registro

```
SET serveroutput on;

BEGIN 
Pack_Insertar.P_Insertar('CLONASEPAN','ORAL','64','mg','COCOAN','OTILIA',20000,'Medio',2);
END;
```

De esta manera mucho mas corta para poder entenderla mejor

```
> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Pack_Insertar
>     IS
>     PROCEDURE P_Insertar (i_d DATOS.Id%type, nom DATOS.Nombre%type, e DATOS.edad%type); END Pack_Insertar;

-----CUERPO DEL PAQUETE INSERTAR-----

create or replace PACKAGE BODY Pack_Insertar
    IS
    PROCEDURE P_Insertar (i_d DATOS.ID%type, nom DATOS.Nombre%type, e DATOS.edad%type)
    is
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Datos VALUES(i_d, nom, e);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Se agrego registros');
    END P_Insertar;
END Pack_Insertar;
```

Insertas un registro

```
SET serveroutput on;

BEGIN 
Pack_Insertar.P_Insertar(1,'luis',64);
END;
```